# How do processor transistor counts keep increasing, without geometric scaling?

Tags: cmos, microprocessor, semiconductors, computer-architecture, vlsi

Reading into the history of the semiconductor industry and Moore's Law, and looking at the ITRS/IRDS documents, I understand that scaling down and modern node names (7nm, 5nm etc) are now "equivalent" and no longer relate to physical dimensions. However, the data showing transistor count suggests that this still follows the 'double every 2 years' trend.

[image: Transistor count still following Moore's Law]

How is this possible, if the transistors themselves are not scaling down at this rate?

Has the counting method changed to suit this? Is it for marketing? Or am I missing something in terms of design that continues to push this figure up?

Comment: Multi-chip modules?

Comment: I think that comment on the diagram 'within power limits' tells it all. While yield is still important for die size, it's power dissipation that really limits how many transistors can be in use at the same time. Hence increasing on-chip cache, that adds mostly 'idle' transistors increases count with minimal increase in power.

Comment: Notice the data shown stops about 7 or 8 years ago...

Comment: Moore's law is not any law. It's just a model for prediction. You could care less about it now.

Comment: @user_1818839 Just to point out that this data has been updated since: https://github.com/karlrupp/microprocessor-trend-data

Comment: Some of the newest processors do have really big dies or multiple dies...

Answer (score 7):

For a given size chip area, the number of transistors on it continues to increase as the size of the transistor -the feature size - decreases.  What that comment is implying is the node name, 5 nm for example, does not have a feature in the transistor, such as a gate width (drawn or actual), that is 5 nm long.

IEEE Spectrum had a [good article](https://spectrum.ieee.org/a-better-way-to-measure-progress-in-semiconductors) about this very thing in one of last year's issues.

Comment: Nevertheless, the areal density of transistors is far from doubling every 14 months today. So either Moore is dead or chips get wider.

Comment: Is this the article: https://spectrum.ieee.org/a-better-way-to-measure-progress-in-semiconductors ? (Scaling is also not uniform. In the past, voltage could also be scaled down. Wires have also been getting "more expensive". That random logic was scaling relatively better in a recent process — if I recall correctly — is also an interesting deviation.)

Comment: @tobalt The original Moore observation was "The complexity for minimum component costs has increased at a rate of roughly a factor of two per year", so if an 18 or 20 month doubling time means Moore's Law is dead then a 14 month doubling time would also since it is longer than 12 months. Physics, engineering, and economics are more complex than implied by a simple model of Moore's Law. Moore also referred to minimum component cost (a higher price per transistor could still support some shrinkage).

Comment: @Paul A. Clayton - Yes, that's the article to which I was referring.

Answer (score 3):

Chips are much larger laterally today. This allows placing more transistors into what qualifies as one chip. Growing sideways also helps keeping power density in check.

For example, large GPUs can be on the order of 600 mm² and consume 300 W, while chips from 20 years ago were closer to a third of this in both metrics.

[Here is an insightful article](https://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2181798) linked by @BruceAbbott . It states:

> [...], in the 25 years since the release of the Intel 80386, transistor area has shrunk by a factor of almost 4,000. [...] An analysis of commercial microprocessors, however, shows that transistor count has actually grown by a factor of 16,000. **One simple reason why transistor growth has outpaced feature size is that processor dies have grown.**

That article also shows that after 2005, the transistor density scaled even slower than the litho resolution, due to power density restrictions (around Figure 5).

Comment: The Itanium processors in the 2000s-2010s for example were 400-700 mm2, so not true chips from 20 years ago where much smaller.  The opposite is actually true, with the reticle limit (maximum die size) shrinking with anamorphic EUV.  Future chips are getting smaller and transistor counts are going up because more of them are being stuffed into a given area.

Comment: @user1850479 If you seriously wanna count Itanium, you also have to count today's Cerebras Wafer Scale stuff... The moore plot of the OP suggests a transistor count doubling every ~14 months. Litho scaling is no longer this fast and hasn't been for a while. Therefore the sole reason Moore was alive longer than Litho scaling kept up, is because chip got larger (on average)

Comment: Itanium was a high end, floating point processor similar to GPUs of today, and in fact, many of the roles filled by Itanium were subsequently filled by GPUs. Comparing products in the same niche makes logical sense.  You can compare to Cerebras too, which is made of 510 mm2 dies stitched together. If you want to argue that lithography scaling is slowing down you should do that, but the claim that chips in the 2000s were 1/3 the size is wrong and doesn't even support that argument.

Comment: "One simple reason why transistor growth has outpaced feature size is that processor dies have grown. While the 80386 microprocessor had a die size of 103 mm2, modern Intel Core i7 dies have an area of up to 296 mm2." - https://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2181798

Comment: Thanks @BruceAbbott I have added some content of that article to my answer.

Comment: @BruceAbbott That is a ten year old article, and a poorly timed one since 4 years later the largest core i7 was 120mm2, and some were smaller than a 386. Problem of course is that you can cherry pick products to prove any point you like, but if you look at the general trend chip sizes tend to fluctuate larger and smaller, but are definitely getting smaller since the reticle limit is shrinking.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that scaling down and modern node names (7nm, 5nm etc) are now "equivalent" and no longer relate to physical dimensions.

You're misunderstanding what is meant by that.  The names are not measurements of any specific dimension or parameter, but they are still roughly proportional to overall transistor area.  More precisely, within a given manufacturer, whatever process they were selling 2 years ago has roughly half as many transistors per area.  They may not call those exact nodes N and N/2 (since the names are arbitrary) but density scaling has still largely been maintained and probably will be for at least a few more years.

> How is this possible, if the transistors themselves are not scaling down at this rate?

Transistors are scaling down at that rate.

Comment: `Transistors are scaling down at that rate.` No, at least not in the last ~ 10 years. First the large foundries have become slower than 2 years per full node. And second each full node is no longer a 2x areal density increase, but maybe closer to 1.7x.. So as a result, the areal density doubles maybe every 3 to 4 years recently.. Compare that to the moore plot of the OP, which shows that transistor count doubles every ~14 months.

Comment: @tobalt Scaling is definitely slowing down from the 2x every 18 months we had 20 years ago, but look at some numbers before you assume I'm wrong.  Apple A14 in 2020 launched 2 years after the A12 on a node with 1.84x the transistor density.  Thus, you get "roughly" double per 2 years.  Doubling in 4 years would be 1.4x per 2 years, which is pretty far off the actual trend.

Answer (score 0):

1. The size of the semiconductor dies, or integrated circuits, have been increasing.
2. Companies are moving towards 3-D IC design.
3. Companies are moving towards wafer-scale computing or wafer-scale IC design, such as Cerebras Systems. See https://cerebras.net/. NVIDIA is exploring wafer-scale computing with TSMC. It is new because it has never been done before with large wafers, such as wafers with a diameter of 300 mm. This allows coarse-grain reconfigurable architecture for the wafer to have much for functional units to reconfigure and exploit. E.g., mapping a very large-scale deep learning network onto it. It haven't been done due to semiconductor manufacturing yield problems, due to very/ultra deep submicron and now nanoscale semiconductor manufacturing process technologies. But, TSMC gets away with it by connecting the isolated dies, which are normally isolated from each other to allow them to be separated from each other (slicing the wafer into dies). Here, TSMC just keeps the wafer intact, and use inter-die interconnects to connect the dies together. This integration of all the dies on a wafer provides much more opportunities to connect the functional blocks than packaged dies with much slower interconnects connecting them on boards. Wafer-scale computing enables all the dies to be connected without separating them via packages and inter-package interconnects. This is not an incremental innovation.

P/S: New transistors that can combine data storage and computation, or devices that perform other tasks (current regulation and retention of past behavior, such as memristors), allow logic gates and circuits to be redesigned with less transistors. Hence, we need not improve IC designs on various metrics, like performance/latency/delay, energy efficiency, and resource usage (number of logic cells/gates used or area of IC layout), by simply using semiconductor manufacturing process technologies that solely focus on improving transistor count.

Comment: Wafer-scale design is nothing new. Can you justify the statement that "companies" (plural) "have moved"...or is it just this one that we have never heard of?

Comment: NVIDIA is exploring wafer-scale computing with TSMC.

It is new because it has never been done before with large wafers, such as wafers with a diameter of 300 mm.

This allows coarse-grain reconfigurable architecture for the wafer to have much for functional units to reconfigure and exploit. E.g., mapping a very large-scale deep learning network onto it.

It haven't been done due to semiconductor manufacturing yield problems, due to very/ultra deep submicron and now nanoscale semiconductor manufacturing process technologies. But, TSMC gets away with it by connecting the isolated dies.

Comment: So NVIDIA/TSMC are **exploring** a technology that is **incrementally better** than what is was in the past. That sounds about right.

Comment: I beg to differ, since the integration of all the dies on a wafer provides much more opportunities to connect the functional blocks than packaged dies with much slower interconnects connecting them on boards.

Wafer-scale computing enables all the dies to be connected without separating them via packages and inter-package interconnects.

This is not incremental.

Comment: But wafer-scale integration has been around for decades, that's my point. The only thing "new" about it is that the wafers are larger and defect rates are lower.

Comment: [That is] conflating old wafer-scale integration with the modern version. Nobody would willfully ship wafer-scale products with pathetic yield/defect rates. The semiconductor companies would go bankrupt rapidly, if they did so.

Yes, people did wafer-scale integration when wafers were <100 mm in diameter.

They stopped doing this when wafers got bigger due to semiconductor manufacturing yield problems, and sliced the wafer into dies instead. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wafer_(electronics). [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: Wafer scale integration was tried in seventies and eighties without success, first success in the twentieth., about half a century later.

Comment: @Giovanni - Hi, Comments can be used for [polite & constructive criticism of an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756). Writing anything unfriendly is [forbidden in comments and Q&A](/help/conduct). Comments from others may have factual errors, but your replies exceeded polite disagreement. Where possible, the problematic parts were removed from your comments, but one was fully deleted. Don't "call people out" in an answer, where their assertion was made in a *comment*. Instead, reply (politely) in a comment. Or you can edit the answer to clarify/add new details - no personal attacks.